# Installing GitLab on Raspian Stretch

Tags: software-installation, apt, packages, git

I am trying to install GitLab on my Pi according to [the official](https://about.gitlab.com/installation/#raspberry-pi-2) instructions.

Until this step everything seems to be working fine:

```
seb@raspi:~ $  sudo curl -sS https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/raspberry-pi2/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
Detected operating system as raspbian/stretch.
Checking for curl...
Detected curl...
Checking for gpg...
Detected gpg...
Running apt-get update... done.
Installing apt-transport-https... done.
Installing /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_raspberry-pi2.list...done.
Importing packagecloud gpg key... done.
Running apt-get update... done.

The repository is setup! You can now install packages.
```

But then the when I try to install it, the package cannot be found.

```
seb@raspi:~ $ sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
E: Paket gitlab-ce kann nicht gefunden werden.
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here? Any idea why this is not working?

I'm running the latest Raspian (Stretch) on a 3B+.

**edit**

```
seb@raspi:~ $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_raspberry-pi2.list
# this file was generated by packages.gitlab.com for
# the repository at https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/raspberry-pi2

deb https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/raspberry-pi2/raspbian/ stretch main
deb-src https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/raspberry-pi2/raspbian/ stretch main
```

Comment: Could you check the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_raspberry-pi2.list` and [edit] that into your post?

Comment: Wow, you guys are really fast. I've edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that GitLab only build packages for Raspbian Jessie, not Stretch. You can see in the [repo link](https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/raspberry-pi2) from the sources file that all the recent releases are tagged "raspbian/jessie", which is  bad sign. I did a bit more searching and [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/2767) confirms that's the case; builds are only available for Jessie at the moment. Your options:

1. Downgrade to Raspbian Jessie.
2. Build GitLab from source using their provided instructions.
3. Try this [hack](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/2767#note_54628738) which suggests running `sudo curl -sS https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/raspberry-pi2/script.deb.sh | sudo os=raspbian dist=jessie bash`  to trick the script into thinking you have Jessie. Note that this might be a poor idea in case you mix Stretch packages with Jessie ones, but this option is provided nevertheless if you want a quick fix to try.

Comment: Thanks. I hope this isn't a stupid question, but should I clean up what I already did ind if how?

Comment: Deleting `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_raspberry-pi2.list` should be enough, @sezi80; it might even work without doing that but removing the file for good measure won't do any harm.